# Most performant file format (Avro/Parquet/ORC) for records with a small number of fields

Tags: google-bigquery, avro, parquet, orc

Im uploading a lot of data (about 160GB uncompressed) to BigQuery.

GZIP is not an option for me and compression is needed here, so that leaves me with Avro/Parquet/ORC with compression on the block level.

I tried looking online but found very little performance comparison between these 3 formats, and the ones I did found were from dodgy looking sites.

My records contain about 20 fields, one field is a record with 2 field in it (can be flatten, doesnt have to be a record).

Im less interested in read speed since BigQuery will be doing that, what is the most performant file format write-wise?

Answer (score 2):

The answer depends in which type of table you are going to create on `BigQuery`.

External Tables are only pointers to files. Everytime you query an External Table `BigQuery` will have to open all the files pointed by the table.

Native Tables are different. When you load a native table, BigQuery imports all the data within it and storage it internally in its own format. Native tables are way more optimized than external table but you have to consider that you will also pay more for it. Its important to remember that with native tables you can load a table without uploading any file in cloud storage at all. Besides that, if you create the table from files in cloud storage, after loading data into a native table you don`t need to keep the files there.

If you are going to create an External Table, you should consider the reading performance. In this case, columnar formats such as `PARQUET` and `ORC` would be a good choice. Otherwise,if you`re going to create a Native Table you should not be worried about reading performance.

About the compression, its proven that `PARQUET` and `ORC` can be more compressed than `AVRO`. Given my experience in `GCP`, I would suggest you to use `PARQUET` format with `DEFLATE` compression if you want an optimized format with good compression.

I hope my answer helps you. If you have any question, please let me know.

Comment: I thought parquet and snappy compressed better than deflate. ORC claims to be better than parquet in some benchmarking, too

Comment: In all the tests I've performed so far in different kinds of data deflate was more profitable than snappy in terms of compression. About the file format, it depends on the platform you're using. GCP started supporting ORC files not much time ago so PARQUET used to be more adviceble to use.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with Parquet simply because of the ease of use and the tools available. If you read the post that are out there comparing write speeds of ORC vs Parquet you will see that they are outdated and that the speed really comes down to the compression library that you are using.

My advice, pick the format with the best tooling in the language that you will be using to do the export. And don't worry about the marginal write speed differences.